# Pandas DataFrame wrong indexing after reading from csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I know very little about python's pandas module. I need to create a `DataFrame` and store it in **.csv** file for my project. I am using `to_csv` and `read_csv` functions. However, when I compared the two frames (before exporting and the imported one) I got different results. This is the the minimal reproducible example:

```
import sys
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

documents = []
documents.append("i love python")
documents.append("foo bar")
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
X = X.T.toarray()
df = pd.DataFrame(X, index=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
df.to_csv(path_or_buf = "db.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv("db.csv")
print(df.axes)
print()
print(df1.axes)
```

And this is what is printed:

```
[Index(['bar', 'foo', 'love', 'python'], dtype='object'), RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)]

[RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1), Index(['Unnamed: 0', '0', '1'], dtype='object')]
```

How can I make the `DataFrame` imported from a **.csv** file identical to the original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:Give index name for the dataframe you are exporting and while reading the exported csv use that name as index. Here I am using `vectors` as index name

```
import sys
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

documents = []
documents.append("i love python")
documents.append("foo bar")
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
X = X.T.toarray()
df = pd.DataFrame(X, index=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
df.index.name = 'vectors'


df.to_csv(path_or_buf="db.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv("db.csv",index_col='vectors')

print(df)
print()
print(df1)
```

**Old answer**: Try exporting csv without index by setting index to false as

```
df.to_csv(path_or_buf="db.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Well, yes, that fixed the problem with the column being added, however the indexing is still different:
`[Index(['bar', 'foo', 'love', 'python'], dtype='object'), RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)]
[RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1), Index(['0', '1'], dtype='object')]` (Sorry for the way it looks in a comment)

Comment: @ВладиславКрутенко please see the updated answer. Let me know if that is what is what you are expecting

Comment: to be honest, I asked this question, because I was getting a KeyError exception while using `loc` with second `DataFrame` and thought this was the cause of it. Your answer solves the question, but the exception is still thrown, so I don't know what the problem is now.

Comment: @ВладиславКрутенко then please update the question which could produce the error.