# ValueError after saving and loading pandas DataFrame to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, valueerror

I am trying to find whether a row exists in a DataFrame based on the values of all columns. I believe I found a solution, but I'm having problems after saving and loading the DataFrame into/from a .csv file.

In the following example, I iterate over each row of the DataFrame, and find the index corresponding to each row -- i.e. the row where all columns are identical to the row being queried).

NB: In my real code, I iterate over a smaller DataFrame and search for rows in a larger DataFrame. But the issue happens in both cases.

```
import pandas  as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])         # Create data frame
df.to_csv(my_filename, index=False)         # Save to csv
df1 = pd.read_csv(my_filename)              # Load from csv

# Find original data in loaded data
for row_idx, this_row in df.iterrows():
    print(np.where((df  == this_row).all(axis=1)))    # This returns the correct index

for row_idx, this_row in df.iterrows():
    print(np.where((df1 == this_row).all(axis=1)))    # This returns an empty index, and a FutureWarning
```

The output is:

```
(array([0]),)
(array([1]),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
tmp.py:25: FutureWarning: Automatic reindexing on DataFrame vs Series comparisons is deprecated and will raise ValueError in a future version.  Do `left, right = left.align(right, axis=1, copy=False)` before e.g. `left == right`
```

After some debugging, I found that the DataFrame loaded from csv is not identical to the original DataFrame:

```
# The DataFrames look identical, but comparing gives me a ValueError:
df
df1
df == df1
```

The output is:

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4

   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "tmp.py", line 30, in <module>
    df == df1

  File "python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 69, in new_method
    return method(self, other)

  File "python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 32, in __eq__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)

  File "python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6851, in _cmp_method
    self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=False, level=None)

  File "python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 288, in align_method_FRAME
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

- Note: This appears to be related to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549172/pandas-dataframe-wrong-indexing-after-reading-from-csv), but the proposed solution, namely specifying the index labels, did not solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are iterating through a data frame I would recommend you to transform your df into a dictionary.

```
df_dict = df.to_dict('records')
```

It is much faster as this great [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-the-most-efficient-way-to-iterate-through-your-pandas-dataframe-4dad88ac92ee#:%7E:text=Vectorization%20is%20always%20the%20first,up%20for%2020%20million%20records.) details.

Now you can enumerate through df_dict and match it to your desired data.

```py
    target_values = {'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'bar', ...}
    for i, row in enumerate(df_dict):
          if row == target_values:
                match_index = i
```

Maybe also a good idea would be to start by matching only one column and if it matches check if everything else is identical too.

Comment: Thanks, it made the iterations MUCH faster! But although it worked well for the simple example I gave, it didn't work in my real dataset -- a large table with survey data, containing both numeric and string values. I  found that the 'if' statement failed because some of the numeric values were converted into strings in the process of saving and loading from .csv (using pandas' `to_csv` and `read_csv`). So I used `df.applymap(str)` to transform the DataFrame values into string before converting to dict and iterating. And now it works well.

Comment: Update: Another reason I found my comparison was failing is related to how pandas handles NaNs -- noted in the [gotchas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html) of pandas. I'll explain with an example:, I had phone numbers originally saved as strings. After saving to .csv, they were saved as integers. However, any missing values are imported as NaN, which by default are treated as float, causing the entire column to be "upgraded" to float. Hence, a phone number of e.g. 555666777, after saved and loaded would become 555666777.0, causing the truth test to fail.